# Django, Celery with Recursion and Twitter API

Tags: python, django, twitter, rabbitmq, celery

I'm working with Django 1.4 and Celery 3.0 (rabbitmq) to build an assemblage of tasks for sourcing and caching queries to Twitter API 1.1. One thing I am trying to implement is chain of tasks, the last of which makes a recursive call to the task two nodes back, based on responses so far and response data in most recently retrieved response.  Concretely, this allows the app to traverse a user timeline (up to 3200 tweets), taking into account that any given request can only yield at most 200 tweets (limitation on Twitter API).

Key components of my tasks.py can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/90HYGGJr), but before pasting, I'll show the chain i'm calling from my Python shell (but that will ultimately be launched via user inputs in the final web app). Given:

```
>>request(twitter_user_id='#1010101010101#, 
  total_requested=1000, 
  max_id = random.getrandbits(128) #e.g. arbitrarily large number)
```

I call:

```
>> res = (twitter_getter.s(request) | 
        pre_get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | 
        get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | 
        timeline_recursor.s()).apply_async()
```

The critical thing is that timeline_recursor can initiate a variable number of get_tweets_for_user_id subtasks. When timeline_recursor is in its base case, it should return a response dict as defined here:

```
@task(rate_limit=None)
def timeline_recursor(request):
    previous_tweets=request.get('previous_tweets', None) #If it's the first time through, this will be None
    if not previous_tweets:
        previous_tweets = [] #so we initiate to empty array
    tweets = request.get('tweets', None) 

    twitter_user_id=request['twitter_user_id']
    previous_max_id=request['previous_max_id']
    total_requested=request['total_requested']
    pulled_in=request['pulled_in']

    remaining_requested = total_requested - pulled_in
    if previous_max_id:
        remaining_requested += 1 #this is because cursored results will always have one overlapping id

    else:
        previous_max_id = random.getrandbits(128) # for first time through loop

    new_max_id = min([tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets])
    test = lambda x, y: x<y

    if remaining_requested < 0:  #because we overshoot by requesting batches of 200
        remaining_requested = 0

    if tweets:
        previous_tweets.extend(tweets)

    if tweets and remaining_requested and (pulled_in > 1) and test(new_max_id, previous_max_id):

        request = dict(user_pk=user_pk,
                    twitter_user_id=twitter_user_id,
                    max_id = new_max_id,
                    total_requested = remaining_requested,
                    tweets=previous_tweets)

        #problem happens in this part of the logic???

        response = (twitter_getter_config.s(request) | get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | timeline_recursor.s()).apply_async()

    else: #if in base case, combine all tweets pulled in thus far and send back as "tweets" -- to be 
          #saved in db or otherwise consumed
        response = dict(
                    twitter_user_id=twitter_user_id,
                    total_requested = total_requested,
                    tweets=previous_tweets)
    return response
```

My expected response for res.result is therefore a dictionary comprised of a twitter user id, a requested number of tweets, and the set of tweets pulled in across successive calls.
However, all is not well in recursive task land. When i run the chain identified above, if I enter *res.status* right after initiating chain, it indicates "SUCCESS", even though in the log  view of my celery worker, I can see that chained recursive calls to the twitter api are being made as expected, with the correct parameters. I can also immediately run result.result even as chained tasks are being executed.  res.result yields an AsyncResponse instance id.  Even after recursively chained tasks have finished running, res.result remains an AsyncResult id.

On the other hand, I *can* access my set of full tweets by going to res.result.result.result.result['tweets'].  I can deduce that each of the chained chained subtasks is indeed occuring, I just don't understand why res.result doesn't have the expected result. The recursive returns that should be happening when timeline_recursor gets its base case don't appear to be propagating as expected.

Any thoughts on what can be done?  Recursion in Celery can get quite powerful, but to me at least, it's not totally apparent how we should be thinking of recursion and recursive functions that utilize Celery and how this affects the logic of return statements in chained tasks.

Happy to clarify as needed, and thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's log from Celery worker: http://pastebin.com/M4SkYBBb

Comment: How do you get 3200 tweets ?  Shouldn't it be 3000 -- the current rate limiting is 15 requests per 15 minute window ( x 200tweets per request )

Comment: The 3200 has to do with the maximum number of tweets twitter will give you for a given user at any given time. For rate limiting, which is what you're talking about my task is configured with the following option: @task(rate_limit="12/m", max_retries=3)
Also, you're allowed 180 calls to this endpoint per 15 minutes, so your numbers are off: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: ah ok.  I thought you were calling get_home_timline (15) , not get_user_timeline (180)

Comment: that rate_limit above is actually 12/second, not minute.

Comment: .apply_async returns an AsyncResult instance.  This is a promise, so the result may not be ready yet, but you can use it to wait for the result of the task(s), or check the progress of it.  However -- you should **never wait for subtasks to complete** as this may lead to resource starvation and eventually deadlock.  I guess the question here is how to do recursion with Celery: You do that by using a another callback: `(twitter_getter_config.s(request) | get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | timeline_recursor.s() | CONTINUE.s())`.

Comment: @asksol -- this makes sense -- as for the CONTINUE subtask, what should this return if we're not in base case (i.e., if chain needs to be called again)? Assuming the chain you've indicated above is called my_chain, should the continue subtask return my_chain.s(*modified_args) -- or should it return my_chain(*modified_args) (e.g., run function as normal, not via Task decorator)? or something else?

Comment: CONTINUE is just the task that recurses, e.g. if you have a list of things to do: `@task def process(items): return group(process.s(item) for item in items)`, here `items` is the stack and the recursion stops when all of the items are processed.  So your CONTINUE task would start this chain as long as there are things left to do.  Whether you call the chain asynchronously or inline in the current process is up to you, both are valid choices and it depends on your choice of granularity[1] for the task.  [1]: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#granularity

Answer (score 1):

what does `apply_async` return ( as in type of object )?

i don't know celery, but in Twisted and many other async frameworks... a call to something like that would immediately return ( usually `True` or perhaps an object that can track state ) as the tasks are deferred into the queue.

again, Not knowing celery , i would guess that this is happening:

you are: defining `response` immediately as the async deferred `task`, but then trying to act on it as if results have come in

you want to be: defining a `callback` routine to run on the results and return a value, once the task has been completed

looking at the celery docs, `apply_async` accepts callbacks via `link` - and i couldn't find any example of someone trying to capture a return value from it.

Comment: While I agree with you about the broad logic of how to implement, this is indeed (as best I can tell) how to implement callbacks in Celery. To link callbacks, you can use the link option you cited, but you can also simply chain tasks together ( http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains), as I'm doing in res = (twitter_getter.s(request) | 
        pre_get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | 
        get_tweets_for_user_id.s() | 
        timeline_recursor.s()).apply_async()

Comment: In celery, it's fine to assign the result of a task to a variable. I believe the expected behavior is for that var.status to be "PENDING" until each task in the chain has returned. Indeed, if you call var.get() and the subtasks are still pending, you won't get a return until execution has completed.  FWIW, I've observed the expected behavior for chains and callbacks in chains that do not use recursion -- the unexpected result seems to be driven by recursive returns not flowing as expected into final result.

Comment: jonathan, you're definitely right about the problem with acting on response after assigning it. I'm now using .get() instead of apply_async() on that chain, which seems to generate the expected recursive calls, but with the unfortunate side effect of causing Celery to hang.

Comment: what does this do `get_tweets_for_user_id.s()` -- usually with deferred calls you would send the function or function + args to be executed later.  is the `.s()` a deferred action from the @task decorator ?

Comment: get_tweets_for_user_id.s() applies the task with that name using the return value of the previous node in the chain.  In celery .s() is a short cut for creating a subtask signature using star arguments (source: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#subtasks)